# What are the possible angles (theta) between two unit vectors $e$ and $f$ if $|e\times f| = 1/2$?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

[image]

This is all I was able to muster so far. Our professor didn't show us what to do in this situation of dot products. What next step could I take?

Comment: You haven't used the assumption that $\vec e$ and $\vec f$ are unit vectors.

Comment: You're right! I forgot unit vectors = 1, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $e$ and $f$ are unit vectors we get
$$\dfrac12=|1||1||\sin\theta|$$
$$\dfrac12=|\sin\theta|$$

Continue from here...

Comment: And then take the arcsin, so the possible angles are $pi/6$ and $5pi/6$ right? I totally forgot about the unit vector thing

Comment: @CurlyFry Yes, you're right.

Comment: @CurlyFry Not only because the condition is $|\sin \theta|=\frac12$ not $\sin \theta=\frac12$